# Why can i use an array but not a structure as a scalar in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, structure

In C, array variables can be used as scalars. For example:

```
char A[5];
if(A) printf("True\n");
```

will print True. Whereas:

```
struct S { int i; } s;
if(s) printf("True\n");
```

will actually fail to compile, giving the error:

*error: used struct type value where scalar is required*

Why is this?

Why can array variables be used as pointers but not structure
variables?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Maybe this is a better way to rephrase the question
Why does C give (scalar) meaning to A but not S?

**EDIT:** My question is more philosophical in nature. I'm trying to understand why C is designed the way it is. Why would an array act like a pointer, yet a structure does not. They both represent contiguous blocks of memory. The structure of that memory is different but why should that matter.

I am not interested in why the compilation fails, i understand that (i demonstrated it didn't i).

Comment: `if(S)` in your example doesn't have any meaning, it is a syntax error. Any discussion past that is pointless.

Comment: @self But WHY doesn't it have any meaning. Why does C give meaning to A but not S?

Comment: @captaincurrie Because `S` doesn't mean anything; `struct S` on the other hand does; it declares a type. A type cannot be used in a if expression.

Comment: @self Because S doesn't meaning anything is not a satisfying answer. Why did the designers of C make the decision to not give S meaning.

Comment: @captaincurrie For the same reason `ch ar` doesnt have any meaning, yet `char` does.

Comment: Unless you get some correspondence or memos from when C was developed, I doubt you'll get an answer to "why". And once the syntax was locked in, by whatever decision or happenstance, there was no going back.

Comment: @chux `S` is not a structure, `struct S` is. I don't see any typedef in the example.

Comment: @captaincurrie Does it not make more sense to ask about `if(s) printf("True\n");`  (lower case s)?

Comment: @self @chux sry i fixed it in my question. It was supposed to be `if(s)` not `if(S)` where s is declared as a `struct S`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the question is *why* do array expressions decay into pointers when `struct` types don't, the answer is basically as follows:

Dennis Ritchie based the design of C on an earlier language known as B (go figure).  In B, when you allocated an array of N elements, as in

```
auto arr[N];
```

the compiler would allocate N+1 cells, one of which would be bound to the identifier `arr` and would contain the offset to the first element of the array, sort of like:

```
           +---+
     arr:  |   | ----+
           +---+     |
            ...      |
           +---+     | 
  arr[0]:  |   | <---+
           +---+
  arr[1]:  |   |
           +---+
  arr[2]:  |   |
           +---+
            ...
           +---+
arr[N-1]:  |   |               
           +---+
```

Ritchie initially kept these semantics, but ran into problems when he introduced `struct` types to the language.  If he defined a struct like

```
struct foo {
  int inode;
  char name[14];
};
```

he wanted an instance of `struct foo` to have a two-byte `int` immediately followed by a 14-byte array of `char`; he didn't want the array pointer stuck in the middle of it.  Eventually he decided to eliminate the array pointer altogether, and designed the language such that whenever it saw an array expression in the source code (and the expression wasn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators), it would *convert* that expression from type "N-element array of `T`" to "pointer to `T`" and have it evaluate to the address of the first element.  So when you allocate an array of N elements in C, you get

```
           +---+      
  arr[0]:  |   | 
           +---+
  arr[1]:  |   |
           +---+
  arr[2]:  |   |
           +---+
            ...
           +---+
arr[N-1]:  |   |               
           +---+
```

There is no separate `arr` object set aside to store the offset to the first element.

This conversion operation is unique to arrays, and this is *why* you can use an array expression as a scalar (technically, as a pointer).  It's unnecessary for structs, since the struct variable itself is an instance of the type, not an offset into a vector of `struct` objects.

For more insight into the *whys* of C, check out [this essay](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html) of Ritchie's.

Comment: Thank you :). This is what i was looking for. What exactly is the offset you mentioned in B. Offset from what?

Comment: @captaincurrie: offset (number of words) from the address of the `arr` variable (B was a "typeless" language, and everything was stored in fixed-length words).  Like in C, array accesses in B were defined such that `arr[i]` was evaluated as `*(arr+i)`; offset `i` cells from the value stored in `arr` and dereference the result.  C retained these semantics, but it doesn't set aside storage for `arr`; it just substitutes the pointer value where necessary.

Answer (score 1):

> Why can array variables be used as pointers but not structure variables?

Array namesconverted to pointer to its first element.

#### C11: 6.3,2.1:

> ...an expression that has type ‘‘array of type’’ is converted to an expression with type ‘‘pointer to type’’ that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.

This is not the case with  structure.

Comment: @chux; Well it is non-standard but widely used to address the issue.

Comment: Your answer rephrases exactly what i demonstrated. I want to know why the language is this way.

Comment: @captaincurrie; I don't know. Ask the language designer :)

Answer (score 1):

one more thing: struct is an aggregate type. pointer to first element of array is scalar type.
**EDIT** 
i think this might be the point :

> A struct is an aggregate data type, like an array.
>
> However, an array has a certain regularity which a struct does not
>   have. An array is an array of some number of something, all the same.
>   E.g. an array of 100 ints. Each array member is an int. You can index
>   which of the 100 ints you want to refer to with an arbitrary
>   expression. This is only possible because all of the elements are the
>   same size and are in order. This observation is similar to the
>   statement that array indexing is pointer arithmetic.
>   A struct, on the other hand, is an aggregate in which the elements can
>   be all different. They are referred to by name, and there is no
>   analogue of a non-constant expression for an index.

from http://www.cdf.toronto.edu/~ajr/209/notes/struct.html

Comment: There are no "class" types in C.

Comment: @macfil Thanks for the EDIT. But i feel the fact that a struct is an aggregate doesn't answer the question why a structure variable doesn't act like a pointer.

Comment: @captaincurrie please re-read article from link in my post. basically, arrays store a bunch of variables of the same type. therefore, you can refer to any variable from array with pointer arithmetic. in fact ``A == A[0] == *(A+0)`` . structs can keep vars of different types and " there is no analogue of a non-constant expression for an index".

Comment: @macfij Great article! I guess maybe that is the reason. Why go to the trouble of representing a structure variable as a pointer if you can't do anything with it. Still, why not. What are you losing by allowing `struct S *p = s` instead of `struct S *p = &s`?

Comment: well, if you have a pointer to struct, you can pass it as an argument to a function and change struct's content inside a function. ps. if you think i helped you, you can mark my answer as accepted :)

Comment: ``struct S *p = s`` will throw an error - it expects an address value (i suppose that s was declared not as a pointer to struct S).

Answer (score 0):

In `C` the value of `A` will be the pointer to the first element of the array.

Consequently  `if(A) printf("True\n");` means if the value of this pointer is not `0` do something. This is perfectly legal `C`(though the pointer to a static array will never be `0`). On the other hand `S` is the name of a structure and `if (S)` has no meaning.

Comment: I know what everything means. I want to know WHY! To me arrays don't seem that much different from arrays. Why is there this difference in representation.

Comment: @captaincurrie a structure is a new type while an array is a collection of instances of some type. Also note `A` is an actual object(array). A fair comparison would be between `A` and `s` an instance of `S`. The compilation will still not succeed, but that is another story.

Comment: Maybe thats it. A struct is a new type. It just seems like arrays and structures are basically the same. One contains elements of the same type, the other variable type.

Comment: "In C the value of A will be the pointer to the first element of the array." No. The value of `A` is an array value, because the variable `A` has array type.

Answer (score 0):

Symbol naming an array is a constant pointing to the first item of the array: `A` is equivalent to `&A[0]`. And this pointer is not `NULL`.
You used that pointer instead of an `int` expression expected by `if()`, so it got converted to integer constant. The pointer is not `NULL` so it became a non-zero integer, thus `if()` condition is satisfied and `print` is called.

And your `struct`, as opposed to pointers, has no default cast to `int`, so can't be used in similar manner.

Comment: "... so it got converted to integer constant."  `if()` statements expect a scalar, not an `int`.  If code was passed a pointer that converted to`UINT_MAX + 1`, it would still be true.